# If P = NP, would that mean P=NP-Complete?

Tags: asymptotics, np-complete

I just started learning about P vs Np and have a basic understanding of P, NP, and NP complete. I just wanted a little clarification on how each interacts with the others. Since NP-Complete is in NP would that mean if P was found to be equal to NP, problems that are NP-Complete would be polynomial time solvable as well? Or would P also need to equal NP-Hard as well in order for NP Complete to be polynomial time solvable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every **NP**-complete problem is also a **NP** problem, by definition. Therefore, if **NP=P**, the same will be true for **NP**-complete problems.

You can't say the same for **NP**-hard problems. These problems include all problems harder then **NP** problems, except for the **NP**-complete problems. In this case, we have that **NP**-hard $\cap $ **NP** = **NP**-complete. So, even if **NP**=**P**, we still will have **NP**-hard $\neq$ **P**.

This picture may help you to understand how these concepts interact.

[image]

Comment: Ah great that really helps. So if P = NP some Np-hard problems would still not be solvable in polynomial times since so NP-hard problems aren't actually in NP?

Comment: Exactly. The name NP-hard means something like *at least as hard as NP*, but not necessarily NP. The hardest NP problems are the NP-complete, and these are the only that are also NP-hard.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help!